# Exclude from list view some articles based on their content type?

Tags: views

i’m listing in a view a list of article filtered with taxonomy terms.

The result is like this :

```
taxonomy term 1
- article A (content type 1)
- article B (content type 1)
- article C (content type 2)

taxonomy term 2
- article D (content type 1)
- article E (content type 1)
- article F (content type 2)

taxonomy term 3
- article G (content type 1)
- article H (content type 1)
- article I (content type 2)
```

How can i exclude from this list some articles based on their content type ? For example, remove "content type 2".

Also, i’ve created a view which contains article C, F, I. How can i add a specific view to this list ?

Here is my view settings :

[image]

Here is the result in front-end :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this rule to Filter criteria section as on screen
[image]

Comment: It’s working. Do you know how can i add a "page view" to this list ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what does "page view" mean in this case

Comment: I’ve created a view which includes 3 articles (article with content type 2). We can see this view in frontend as a page. I would like to display link to this view in this list.Is that more clear ? Maybe i should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add link to this views manually in footer. Go to footer section and add unfiltered text as on screen

[image]

This link will be in the bottom of list

Comment: It seems a good idea. But i have several views to add all associated with taxonomy terms. So it would not be possible to have them in the footer. They have to be in the list because they are associated with taxonomy terms.

Comment: In this case you can create tab menu with all this views as described here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1578582

Comment: I'v created an other question for this purpose since you have already answered my question : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238357/display-a-view-link-in-an-other-view-list-of-articles

Answer (score 0):

Add new Link field in View like displayed in below image to add Link in view like "Read More".

[image]

Text it Like "Read More" so it will link to detail view of that article.

[image]

in Rewrite Results you can add link , class , text etc

[image]

Comment: I'v created an other question for this purpose since Andrew Kozoriz have already answered my initial question : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238357/display-a-view-link-in-an-other-view-list-of-articles