# How to display a view link in another view?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I’m listing in a view a list of article filtered with taxonomy terms.

The result is like this :

```
taxonomy term 1
- article A
- article B
- article C

taxonomy term 2
- article D
- article E
- article F

taxonomy term 3
- article G
- article H
- article I
```

Here is the view configuration :
[image]

I’ve also created a view which contains 3 articles and which have the same taxonomy relationship than articles.

I can see this view as a page like this : http://my-site.com/my-view

Here is my view configuration :
[image]

I would like to display this view link in the listing :

```
taxonomy term 1
- article A
- article B
- article C
- link to view A (associated with term 1)

taxonomy term 2
- article D
- article E
- article F
- link to view B (associated with term 2)

taxonomy term 3
- article G
- article H
- article I
- link to view C (associated with term 3)
```

How can I do that? I can't find a field in view configuration to display this view.

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer No.I’ve tested the module and i found it interesting but i didn’t reach my goal. I think i have to make a different approach on that question.

Comment: any advance with your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of these modules:

[Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

> There are a lot of cases in views where you want to embed a list
>   inside each row. One example could be, you have a list of groups, and
>   for each groups you want to list the first and last name of all of
>   their members.

[Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield)

> Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
>   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I can understand what you want, you can do it in 2 different method:

**Method 1:**

Within the first view (list of article filtered with taxonomy terms) add a field of type: **Global: Custom text** which will allow to create custom text or link and then add **the link of your second view** inside the **Global: Custom text**

**Method 2:**

You have to install and enable the [Views field view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

> There are a lot of cases in views where you want to embed a list
>   inside each row. One example could be, you have a list of groups, and
>   for each groups you want to list the first and last name of all of
>   their members.
>
> This can be achieved with this module, as views_field_view allows you
>   to embed one view into another view and pass arguments along.

and then go to your first view (list of article filtered with taxonomy terms) and add the **Global:view**, and now from within the settings of this field select **your second view** and voila !

**Note:** Using method # 2 will embed/display the entire **second view** within the **first view**.